# Postgresql selecting for common elements of another column for the queried elements in our column

Tags: sql, postgresql

Table (both columns are not unique and do not have primary key)

```
 C1     |    C2
 ===============
 2      |    1
 3      |    1
 4      |    1
 4      |    2
 4      |    3
 5      |    1
 5      |    2
 6      |    1
 6      |    3
 7      |    1
```

If I query for 3 and 4 of column C1 I should get following table. Not a specific query I could query something else in column instead of 3 or 4.

Result:

```
C1     |    C2
===============
 3      |    1
 4      |    1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
SELECT C1, C2
FROM (
  SELECT C1, C2, COUNT(C1) OVER (PARTITION BY C2) AS cnt
  FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT C1, C2
    FROM mytable
    WHERE C1 IN (3,4) ) t ) s
WHERE s.cnt = 2
```

The windowed version of `COUNT` is used to count the number of *distinct* ocurrences of `C1` within each `C2` partition. If this number is equal to `2` then we apparently have a match.

Note that an additional level of sub-querying is required, the one with the `DISTINCT` clause, since `COUNT(DISTINCT ...) OVER ...` is not supported in Postgresql.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ae507/6)

Comment: what is t in the query?

Comment: @telukir It is just an alias. You *have* to use an alias for *each* sub-query used.

Comment: @telukir: it's a (required) alias for the derived table. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-SUBQUERIES

Comment: I think the number 2 is dependent on the number of values there in IN statement. How to make this number as variable. Which means if I query for 4 numbers then basically I would require s.cnt = 4, am I correct?

Comment: @KiranTelukunta If you know the values beforehand then you know their count as well, don't you?

Comment: I would not know the values before hand, in that case I would require a variable... how to do that? I mean something like s.cnt = COUNT(IN (3,4,5,.....)).

Comment: @KiranTelukunta Maybe using a CTE like [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ae507/9)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select c1,min(c2) as c2 from table
where c1 in (3,4)
group by c1
```

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos, you have an extra (3,0) row in you SQLfiddle. Remove that row and you'll get correct answer when executing this query!

Comment: @jarlh Yes, but the query is supposed to work with *any* set of data.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos, you may be correct, I've had issues understanding the question... Not a very well described problem.